# How to pass any External link as a url paramenter using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, parameter-passing

I am totally new to javascript.

I have a site `mysite.com`, with tonnes of External links and I am trying to track every external link and append it as parameter to an external domain like

> myanothersite.com/redirect.html?url=http://externallink.com`

using javascript.

myanothersite.com/redirect.html is a page which it redirects to passed url parameter after 5 seconds and i have created this page successfully.

In a nutshell, when a visitor clicks on external link, I don't want him to visit the external site directly. Instead I want to do this,

```
mysite.com 
--> Visitor clicks on http://externallink.com 
--> myanothersite.com/redirect.html?url=http://externallink.com 
--> http://externallink.com
```

so, here I am trying write a js code that automatically detects external link and append it as a query parameter to

> myanothersite.com/redirect.html?url=

Comment: _“so,here i am trying write a js code”_ - okay, let us see what you tried then, please. [ask], [mre]

Comment: use url-encoding

Comment: `$(function() { $("a[href^=http]").on("click",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); location =  "myanothersite.com/redirect.html?url="+encodeURIComponent(this.href); }); });`

Answer (score -1):

there is a package on npm which may help you

[qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs)

In addition, the. window object is a global object which can handle redirects, open a new window, or reload. So you can go through the documentations and red that one as well.

If you are looking for a simpler solution, you can try this

grab the link from the window object like this and store in a variable

```
var location = window.location.href
```

Then split it around the 'url=' like this

```
var splitArray = location.split('url=');
console.log(splitArray[1]);
```

You should see your url in the console. use it wherever you want

Comment: You did not read the question correctly.